# GHCI vs compiled function difference

Tags: haskell

The goal is to input a float and return a string containing only the absolute value of the digits before the dot.

Basically putting in -14.4 should return "14"

When I type in the sequence of instructions via GHCI I run into no problem.

Yet when I use it in a compiled function like this:

```
testFront :: Float -> String
testFront x = tillDot $ show $ abs $ x

tillDot :: String -> String
tillDot x = case x of
  [] -> ""
  x -> takeWhile (/= '.') x
```

then suddenly I run into the error shown in the the screenshot.

[image]

I figured out that I had to put the negative number using ().

The question is: Can I somehow do this within the file? Something that automatically puts my input into ()? Or do I have to write a seperate function that does that?

Comment: It's interesting that you started your GHCi session with `abs $ -14.4` instead of `abs -14.4` which would have raised the same error. Later on you then use `testFront -14.4` and not `testFront $ -14.4` which would have worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The question is: Can I somehow do this within the file? Something that automatically puts my input into `()`? Or do I have to write a seperate function that does that?

The reason you need to wrap these into parenthesis is because there is a difference between:

```
f - 14
```

and:

```
f (-14)
```

Indeed, for the former it will subtract `14` from the value of a variable named `f`. If `f` is for example `25`, it will return `11`.

For the latter it will call a function `f` with `-14` as argument.

Except for a minus, no operator has an unary form. The parenthesis are thus necessary to disambiguate between the unary and binary form.

Comment: So I assume this means that the user is forced to put their negative number into () parenthesis and that I can't somehow convert the unary into binary form, right?

Comment: @VulpesNix: indeed. The function also does not "know" the expression of the parameter, so you can not fix this. If I recall correctly there has been a lot of discussion about whether to allow an unary minus in the first place, and not just use `f (negate 14)`, so to prevent ever writing something like `f (-14)` in the first place for an unary minus, since it is the one (and only) exception in the entire language.

Comment: @VulpesNix `f -1` does not call function `f`, it calls function `(-)` (subtraction) with arguments `f` and `1`. There's nothing you can do in `f` to prevent this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Bit annoying but I guess that's Haskell :)

Comment: @VulpesNix: well it is indeed different than most other programming languages, and that makes it annoying. But t.b.h. after a while one gets used to it, and actually it makes the language simpler imho. In fact one could also see `(-14)` as *operator sectioning* and a function, and it is thus a bit "ugly" that this is an exception in a language that is otherwise actually quite consistent.

Comment: @VulpesNix There is a GHC extension that can address this to some extent: [`-XNegativeLiterals`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/exts/negative_literals.html#extension-NegativeLiterals)